# Application Error SDXHelper.exe module ntdll.dll

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, microsoft-office-365, remote-desktop-services

I'm wondering if anyone out there can help me with a re-occurring event that I'm getting on my Windows Server 2012 R2 RDS Servers. The servers are running Office 365 ProPlus Version 2003 (Build 12624.20466 Click-to-Run) Monthly Channel.

```
Faulting application name: SDXHelper.exe, version: 16.0.12624.20466, time stamp: 0x5e94e78d
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.19678, time stamp: 0x5e82c0f7
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x000e5d84
Faulting process id: 0x27b4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d61d2999302444
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\SDXHelper.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: da39705b-891c-11ea-80e5-00155d0f069e
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I used to get the event every now and then. However, its popped up every day for the last 4 days. The timings don't appear to have a pattern with some happening in the morning, late morning, mid day, and afternoon so I don't think this error is related to a certain user pattern.

I've performed an `sfc /VERIFYFILE="c:\windows\system32\ntdll.dll"` and it has come back with no issues with the .ddl file. Has anyone else run into this issue before?

Comment: Does the issue ocuur aftr installing recent Windows or Office 365 updates? Try to uninstall recent Windows updates to have a check.You can also [revert to an earlier version of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2770432/how-to-revert-to-an-earlier-version-of-office-2013-or-office-2016-clic). Check if the issue is caused by Windows/Office updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office 365 is [not supported on Windows Server 2012 R2](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=2111390), weird behavior is expected in these conditions. You should upgrade to Windows Server 2019.